# Debugging not receiving some user's email address

Tags: facebook, email

I'm an admin of this facebook application. And when user join the app, I have "scope=email" so that my app can read the user's email address.

This is working mostly, but I just found that some player's email are missing in the db.

My question is..

How do I debug and see if facebook is returning email address for this particular user (I have facebook id)? I tried "Graph API Explorer", but it seems that I can only see my own email address.

And how do I get a list of permission that a user has given to my app?

Comment: You can query for permissions given to your application by `/user_id/permissions` endpoint.

Comment: I've tried it. Same situation, I can only see the my own account's permissions, for other user I get {
  "data": [
  ]
}

Comment: If you are getting nothing that means that the user has not installed your application. Else you would have received `installed` key in returned result.

Comment: I'm sure that user installed the app, because it is one of my fake user account that I'm using to test the app.. Here is what I do, I go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer, select my application from the drop down list at the top right corner (facebook will populate the access token), then I type in this /<user id>/permissions in the graph api.

Comment: Try with app access token instead. It requires app access token. Check  documentation [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) for same.

Comment: Yep, I'm trying with app access token, otherwise I'd get "An access token is required to request this resource" error.

Comment: I'm starting to think that the only way I'd get these information is to write my own app or script. Facebook's developer tool doesn't seem to be suitable for the need.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't remove the app from your fake account to test the whole process and you haven't cleaned up your db? Why don't you log into the fake account and view what apps it has authorized and what permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did more investigations and found that we need **the player's access token** - an active one.